# Netbeans keyboard shortcuts that do not work with a non-English keyboard layout

Tags: netbeans

I believe this problem has been present for a few years in Netbeans, in different non-English keyboard layouts (see for example [Shortcuts in NetBeans don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618638/shortcuts-in-netbeans-dont-work)).

**Premises:**

- I am using Netbeans 7.3.1, and coding in Java
- I use a non-US keyboard layout (Swedish), and Netbeans picks up all the Swedish keys correctly when typing them in the code window.

**The problem:**

The keyboard shortcuts that use keys that are mapped the same in Swedish and English layout (normal letters for example) work fine, but the keyboard shortcuts that use keys that are mapped differently behave inconsistently.

**Example:**

Toggle comment (Ctrl+Slash). Slash is Shift+7 in Swedish layout, Ctrl+Shift+7 brings up project properties. Slash in US layout is the key left of right shift, labeled - in Swedish layout. If I press that, Netbeans recognizes this as - and performs the standard behavior for Ctrl+- (a code fold).

Complete line (Ctrl+Shift+;). The key labeled ; in Swedish layout has < in US. This combo brings upp the bookmarks tab. The key labeled ; in US layout has a Swedish letter, this combo does nothing.

I have seen questions by people in different languages asking about one specific shortcut or another not working, and the answer is usually to edit the Netbeans keymap, I wanted to connect a few more dots. Does anybody have further experience or suggestions?

Comment: The same problem with Russian keyboard layout: Ctrl+C (copy) and Ctrl+V (paste) don't work with Russian, but it works in English, of course. NetBeans  8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another shortcut appearing on the keyboard shortcuts card for for 7.3.1 that this affects is *Move caret to matching brace* (Ctrl+[).

These issues have been around since at least 2008: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=155117. As of last year, the developers seem undecided if it is worthwhile to fix: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227247

However -

*Toggle comment* has an alternative shortcut - *Ctrl+Shift+C* - originally aimed at German keyboards, but which should work for all remotely mainstream layouts since it uses no special key.

*Move caret to matching brace* apparently has the alternative *Ctrl+^* aimed at French layout, but does not work in Swedish for example.

*Complete line* has no alternative I could find.

**Conclusion**

Personally I will be using Ctrl+Shift+C for comments, and entering my own alternative for Complete line in Options > Keymap. Move caret to matching brace / bracket, though named on the shortcuts card, does not show up as a reassignable here as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and it had a simple solution and the solution was the font change.

In Netbeans (`tool-option-font&زcolor-fon`t). I changed my default font.